# using Xcode with MonoDevelop when the Custom View Controller doesn't directly inherit from UIViewController

Tags: c#, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to use the Navigation part of Three20.  To interface with the Three20 assemblies I have had to create a Binding Project with classes that bind to the classes within Three20.  One of those is a `UIViewController` that has additions to the UIKit `UIViewController`.  This means that my ViewControllers have to inherit from this class if I'm going to use the Three20 features of URL-based navigation.

Here's the problem:

If I inherit from the Three20 `UIViewController` and then attempt to edit the .xib in Xcode, MonoDevelop doesn't create the .h and .m files needed by Xcode to add Outlet etc.

Does anybody know of a way of having a View controller that doesn't directly inherit from `MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewcontroller` and is editable in Xcode?

here's my code:

```
public partial class TestViewController : TTBaseViewController
{
```

.......

and in a separate MonoTouch binding project:

```
[BaseType (typeof (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController))]
interface TTBaseViewController
{   
    /**
     * Displays a controller inside this controller.
     *
     * TTURLMap uses this to display newly created controllers.  The default does nothing --
     * UIViewController categories and subclasses should implement to display the controller
     * in a manner specific to them.
     */
    [Bind("addSubcontroller:animated:transition:")]
    void AddSubcontroller(UIViewController controller, bool animated, UIViewAnimationTransition transition);
```

which produces a class definition like this:

```
[Register("TTBaseViewController", true)]
public partial class TTBaseViewController : MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController {
    static IntPtr selAddSubcontrollerAnimatedTransition_ = Selector.GetHandle ("addSubcontroller:animated:transition:");
    static IntPtr selRemoveFromSupercontroller = Selector.GetHandle ("removeFromSupercontroller");
    static IntPtr selRemoveFromSupercontrollerAnimated_ = Selector.GetHandle ("removeFromSupercontrollerAnimated:");
    static IntPtr selKeyForSubcontroller_ = Selector.GetHandle ("keyForSubcontroller:");
    static IntPtr selSubcontrollerForKey_ = Selector.GetHandle ("subcontrollerForKey:");
    static IntPtr selPersistView_ = Selector.GetHandle ("persistView:");
    static IntPtr selRestoreView_ = Selector.GetHandle ("restoreView:");
    static IntPtr selSuperController = Selector.GetHandle ("superController");
    static IntPtr selSetSuperController_ = Selector.GetHandle ("setSuperController:");
    static IntPtr selTopSubcontroller = Selector.GetHandle ("topSubcontroller");
    static IntPtr selNavigatorURL = Selector.GetHandle ("navigatorURL");
    static IntPtr selOriginalNavigatorURL = Selector.GetHandle ("originalNavigatorURL");
    static IntPtr selFrozenState = Selector.GetHandle ("frozenState");
    static IntPtr selDoNavigatorGarbageCollection = Selector.GetHandle ("doNavigatorGarbageCollection");

    static IntPtr class_ptr = Class.GetHandle ("TTBaseViewController");

    [Export ("init")]
    public  TTBaseViewController () : base (NSObjectFlag.Empty)
    {
        Handle = MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (this.Handle, Selector.Init);

    }

    public TTBaseViewController (NSObjectFlag t) : base (t) {}

    public TTBaseViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this still an issue with MonoDevelop 2.8.8.3?

This sounds like an issue that has already been fixed in the betas.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I've downloaded the Beta release 2.8.8.3 but there's no change.

Comment: Just to be sure that I understand correctly, TestViewController.h is not getting generated when exporting to Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

ok, it seems that the problem occurs when inheriting from a class created in a Binding Project AND referencing the Binding Project rather than the .dll created by the Binding Project.  If you reference the dll directly the .h files are created normally.

Make development/testing a bit of a pain though